# Swift: Sort array of objects alphabetically

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have this:

```
class Movies {
  Name:String
  Date:Int
}
```

and an array of [Movies]. How do I sort the array alphabetically by name? I've tried:

`movieArr = movieArr.sorted{ $0 < $1 }`

and

`movieArr = sorted(movieArr)`

but that doesn't work because I'm not accessing the name attribute of Movies.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

In the closure you pass to `sort`, compare the properties you want to sort by. Like this:

```
movieArr.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
```

or the following in the cases that you want to bypass cases:

```
movieArr.sorted { $0.name.lowercased() < $1.name.lowercased() }
```

***Sidenote:** Typically only types start with an uppercase letter; I'd recommend using `name` and `date`, not `Name` and `Date`.*

---

Example, in a playground:

```
class Movie {
    let name: String
    var date: Int?
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var movieA = Movie("A")
var movieB = Movie("B")
var movieC = Movie("C")

let movies = [movieB, movieC, movieA]
let sortedMovies = movies.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
sortedMovies
```

`sortedMovies` will be in the order `[movieA, movieB, movieC]`

> Swift5 Update

```
channelsArray = channelsArray.sorted { (channel1, channel2) -> Bool in
            let channelName1 = channel1.name
            let channelName2 = channel2.name
            return (channelName1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(channelName2) == .orderedAscending)
}
```

Comment: use movies.sort instead of movies.sorted @Mike S

Comment: @julian-król You forgot to edit the other `sorted` to `sort` in the answer. Note: this is not a typo, `sorted` was correct in Swift 1 but has become `sort` in Swift 2.

Comment: okay I will fix that, I thought that sorted is the other method where you need to pass array so it would be like sorted(array, {$0.name < $1.name }) this is why I placed it is a typo. thanks

Comment: @JulianKról To be precise: the old `sort` is now `sortInPlace` and the old `sorted` is now `sort`. There's no problem with your edit, it just needed to be complete. :)

Comment: thanks for explanation. Improved my edit, should be fine, please take a look :)

Comment: Beware, this won't work when sorting string that may or may not be capitalized. Comparing the `.lowercaseString` will solve this problem.

Comment: @EricAya Note it is `sorted` in Swift 3 again :D .

Answer (score 56):

With Swift 3, you can choose one of the following ways to solve your problem.

---

### 1. Using [`sorted(by:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) with a `Movie` class that does not conform to `Comparable` protocol

If your `Movie` class does not conform to `Comparable` protocol, you must specify in your closure the property on which you wish to use Array's `sorted(by:​)` method.

`Movie` class declaration:

```
import Foundation

class Movie: CustomStringConvertible {

    let name: String
    var date: Date
    var description: String { return name }

    init(name: String, date: Date = Date()) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let avatarMovie = Movie(name: "Avatar")
let titanicMovie = Movie(name: "Titanic")
let piranhaMovie = Movie(name: "Piranha II: The Spawning")

let movies = [avatarMovie, titanicMovie, piranhaMovie]
let sortedMovies = movies.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
// let sortedMovies = movies.sorted { $0.name < $1.name } // also works

print(sortedMovies)

/*
prints: [Avatar, Piranha II: The Spawning, Titanic]
*/
```

---

### 2. Using [`sorted(by:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) with a `Movie` class that conforms to `Comparable` protocol

However, by making your `Movie` class conform to `Comparable` protocol, you can have a much concise code when you want to use Array's `sorted(by:​)` method.

`Movie` class declaration:

```
import Foundation

class Movie: CustomStringConvertible, Comparable {

    let name: String
    var date: Date
    var description: String { return name }

    init(name: String, date: Date = Date()) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Movie, rhs: Movie) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    static func <(lhs: Movie, rhs: Movie) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let avatarMovie = Movie(name: "Avatar")
let titanicMovie = Movie(name: "Titanic")
let piranhaMovie = Movie(name: "Piranha II: The Spawning")

let movies = [avatarMovie, titanicMovie, piranhaMovie]
let sortedMovies = movies.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
// let sortedMovies = movies.sorted { $0 < $1 } // also works
// let sortedMovies = movies.sorted(by: <) // also works

print(sortedMovies)

/*
 prints: [Avatar, Piranha II: The Spawning, Titanic]
 */
```

---

### 3. Using [`sorted()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2905744-sorted) with a `Movie` class that conforms to `Comparable` protocol

By making your `Movie` class conform to `Comparable` protocol, you can use Array's `sorted()` method as an alternative to `sorted(by:​)`.

`Movie` class declaration:

```
import Foundation

class Movie: CustomStringConvertible, Comparable {

    let name: String
    var date: Date
    var description: String { return name }

    init(name: String, date: Date = Date()) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Movie, rhs: Movie) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    static func <(lhs: Movie, rhs: Movie) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let avatarMovie = Movie(name: "Avatar")
let titanicMovie = Movie(name: "Titanic")
let piranhaMovie = Movie(name: "Piranha II: The Spawning")

let movies = [avatarMovie, titanicMovie, piranhaMovie]
let sortedMovies = movies.sorted()

print(sortedMovies)

/*
 prints: [Avatar, Piranha II: The Spawning, Titanic]
 */
```

Comment: Hey, Is there any diff. between 2nd and 3rd (except `movies.sorted(by: <)` and `movies.sorted()`) ?

Comment: `sorted(by:)` and `sorted()` are two different methods. You can use `array.sorted()` as an alternative for `array.sorted(by: <)`.

Comment: Yes, just asking in case of class definition do we need to change anything? I mean, can we have same class definition for both `sorted(by:)` and `sorted()` ?

Comment: Yes, you can have the same implementation of your class/struct that, in any case, has to conform to `Comparable` protocol.

Comment: I have Array with customObject when i shoer in ascending order it's not shorting in proper way.  
  `"1" "14""28""31""4""42""49"`

Comment: But it Should be `["1""4""14""28""28""31""42""49"]`

Answer (score 21):

```
let sortArray =  array.sorted(by: { $0.name.lowercased() < $1.name.lowercased() })
```

Comment: adding .lowercased() worked for me after a long period of trying. I don't understand why, since all text were lowercased to begin with.

Comment: when use lowercased() will change all names to lower case to sorted properly :)

Answer (score 14):

For those using Swift 3, the equivalent method for the accepted answer is:

```
movieArr.sorted { $0.Name < $1.Name }
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of these answers are wrong due to the failure to use a locale based comparison for sorting. Look at localizedStandardCompare()

Answer (score 1):

Sorted array
Swift 4.2

```
arrayOfRaces = arrayOfItems.sorted(by: { ($0["raceName"] as! String) < ($1["raceName"] as! String) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Messages {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Messages> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Messages>(entityName: "Messages")
    }

    @NSManaged public var text: String?
    @NSManaged public var date: Date?
    @NSManaged public var friends: Friends?

}

    //here arrMessage is the array you can sort this array as under bellow 

    var arrMessages = [Messages]()

    arrMessages.sort { (arrMessages1, arrMessages2) -> Bool in
               arrMessages1.date! > arrMessages2.date!
    }*
```