# Making unordered items in an array to always in same order

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

My app has a VC with tableview which contains 10 cells(questions). User selects whatever they apply to them and press `"next"` button.  Then, it goes to next VC has a table view and initialize corresponding section to the questions.

For example, if I select "Question1, Question 2" out of 10 questions, then it should make two sections which have titles of "Question1" and "Question 2".

Right now I add a question selected in an array like following:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        result.append(allCriteria[indexPath.row])
    }
```

Then, when `"next"` button is pressed, it passes `result` array to next VC. Based on the array "result" is passed, it initializes sections in order.

The problem is that it changes the order of section if I press the questions in random order. And this is expected.
Would there be anyway solve this?

In short, even if a user selects questions in order of `"Question2, Question1"`, I would like sections to be made in order of `"Question1, Question2"`

`result` array is type of `[Question]!` and `Question class` is like below:

```
class Question {

    var documents: [Document] = []
    var title: String
    var description: String

    init(dict: [String:AnyObject] ) {
        // parse dict to generate a bunch of documents, add them to self.documents
        self.title = dict["Title"] as! String
        self.description = dict["Description"] as! String

        let documentsDicts = dict["Documents"] as! [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]

        for dictionary in documentsDicts {
            let document = Document(dict: dictionary)
            self.documents.append(document)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the `Question` to the `result` array when user selects a cell, you can just add the `indexPath` of that cell to an array. When user clicks next, you just sort that `indexPath` array by ascending order, then based on that, you just generate the `result` array and pass it to the next view controller, something like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    indexPathArray.append(indexPath)
}

func next() {
    let sorted = indexPathArray.sort(<)
    let result = sorted.map {
        (var index) -> Question in 
            return allCriteria[index]
    }
    // ........
}
```

Comment: Is that a syntax error in sort(<)? It seems like it is not recognizing it.

Comment: That's the new syntax, I'm using xCode 7.2. Since ascending is the default sorting order, you can just simply do `let sorted = indexPathArray.sort()` or even simpler `indexPathArray.sortInPlace()` which sorts it in place.

Comment: I don't know why but if I use < it tells me it is an ambiguous argument. But I implemented my own method which is essentially same as < and figured it out. Thanks. It does not look like I can call sort or sortInPlace without arguments as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719744/swift-sort-array-of-objects-alphabetically), a solution can be to sort your array alphabetically by question's title and do something like this:

```
result.sort { $0.title < $1.title }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3

```
self.resultArry.sort(by: { $0.title < $1.title })
```