# How to sort an array chronologically?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, date

I shall like to sort out an array in order chronological. I know not at all how to take myself there ... Here is the array:

```
 [["FM", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 18:16:29 +0000", "TYPE", "inbox"], ["FM", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 18:17:24 +0000", "TYPE", "no", "send"], ["Jm", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 19:25:27 +0000", "TYPE", "no", "send"]]
```

I tried with that but that did not work ....

```
 str.sort({$0[3].date > $1[3].date})
```

I shall like the most recent date at the beginning, the output should be like this:

```
 [["Jm", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 19:25:27 +0000", "TYPE", "no", "send"], ["FM", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 18:17:24 +0000", "TYPE", "no", "send"], ["FM", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 18:16:29 +0000", "TYPE", "inbox"], ["FM", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 18:17:24 +0000", "TYPE", "no", "send"]]
```

Comment: what should be your output?

Comment: This has the thing you need in every language -
https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_using_a_custom_comparator

Comment: Did you try `str.sort {$0[3].date > $1[3].date} `
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719744/swift-sort-array-of-objects-alphabetically

Comment: Not working with {$0[3].date > $1[3].date} ...

Comment: @POL you have to use COMPARE to sort with dates.Example-: message.sorted(by: {$0.date?.compare($1.date! as Date) == .orderedAscending})

Comment: `$0[3].date` What's that call `.date` ? `$0[3]` is a String. You need to convert it into `(NS)Date` with `(NS)DateFormatter`. Also, I strongly suggest to use a proper class/struct rather than a array to keep your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dateformatter to convert strings into date first and then compare them:

```
let str = [["FM", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 18:16:29 +0000", "TYPE", "inbox"], ["FM", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 18:17:24 +0000", "TYPE", "no", "send"], ["Jm", "TEL", "ID", "2017-06-17 19:25:27 +0000", "TYPE", "no", "send"]]

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

let sorted = str.sorted(by: {dateFormatter.date(from: $0[3])!  > dateFormatter.date(from: $1[3])!})
```