# Swift sort an Array

Tags: swift, algorithm

I want to sort an array

like this:

```
let elements = ["S","A","C","C","T","E","E","E","F","S","S","A","A","C"]
```

I tried do this

```
var currentElement = ""
var newElements:[String] = []
for element in elements {
    if currentElement != element{
        currentElement = element
        newElements.append(element)
    }
}
```

but `print["S", "A", "C", "T", "E", "F", "S", "A", "C"]`

How to sort this to `["A","C","E","F","S","T"]`

Comment: Wtf, you are not even sorting anything in your if condition, it's not even AN ATTEMPT to sort anything, you are just suppressing the duplicates ! Looks to me a lot like some kind of homework you don't want to do, get back to work and search on google.

Comment: First: Unique values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624331/unique-values-of-array-in-swift Then sort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719744/swift-sort-array-of-objects-alphabetically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to remove the duplicates and then sort it, right?

You can convert it to a `Set`, and then call `sorted()`:

```
let elements = ["S","A","C","C","T","E","E","E","F","S","S","A","A","C"]
let newElements = Set(elements).sorted() // ["A", "C", "E", "F", "S", "T"]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let elements = ["S","A","C","C","T","E","E","E","F","S","S","A","A","C"]

let sortedElements = elements.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})

print(sortedElements)
```

prints:

```
["A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "E", "E", "E", "F", "S", "S", "S", "T"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ComparisonResult to sort your array alphabetical, because Set(elements).sorted() and you have lowercase characters, the result of sort will be wrong.

```
var elements = ["S","A","C","C","T","E","E","E","F","S","S","A","A","C"]

elements = elements.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }

//the output["A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "E", "E", "E", "F", "S", "S", "S", "T"]
```