# Sort user list: SwiftUI - Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am creating an application in Swift, and I am creating a section with a calendar where you will be able to see the list of users with a numeric data entered by them.
These data are collected in a structure as follows:

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var timetables: [String]

    var toCheck: [String] {
        return [name, surname]
    }
}
```

User information is displayed like this:

```
ForEach(administratorManager.users) { user in
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(user.name).font(.subheadline) 
            Text(user.surname).font(.subheadline)
            Text(user.orari[day]).font(.subheadline)
        }
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

And they are displayed on the screen like this:  [Photo of the list displayed on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an6te.jpg)

The data is sorted according to their position in the database:
[image: Photo of the data in the database]

I'd like to sort the list by the number entered under the user's first and last name (the smallest above and so on). Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Are you asking how to [sort an array of strings in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719744/swift-sort-array-of-objects-alphabetically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `administratorManager.users` is a `Swift.Array` (or other sortable in-memory collection), you can sort it however you want. This is one possible way you might sort on the surname and name fields:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ForEach(administratorManager.users.sorted(using: [
        KeyPathComparator(\.surname, order: .forward),
        KeyPathComparator(\.name, order: .forward),
    ])) { user in
        Text(user.name)
    }
}
```

If you want to sort on the initial element of the associated `timetables` array, you can traverse a property with the [`KeyPathComparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/keypathcomparator):

```swift
KeyPathComparator(\.timetables.first, order: .forward)
```

And if the value needs to be calculated, you can add it as a calculated property:

```swift
extension User {
    var minTimetable: String? {
        timetables.min()
    }
}
```

and then reference that property from the comparator:

```swift
KeyPathComparator(\.minTimetable, order: .forward)
```